# PayPal API Returning code 10400: Order total is missing

Tags: php, api, paypal

I am trying to call the PayPal API command SetExpressCheckout.

The parameters that I am passing are the following (URL parameters):

```
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
VERSION=2.7.1
PWD=PWD
USER=USER
SIGNATURE=SIG
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=1.36
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
RETURNURL=https://url/confirm/?id=ID
CANCELURL=https://url/cancel/?id=ID
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=EUR
REQCONFIRMSHIPPING=0
NOSHIPPING=1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=ITEM_NAME
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=1.36
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital
BUTTONSOURCE=PP-ECWizard
```

I have looked at numerous other posts that illustrate the same problem and from the answers it seems that I have added all the parameters that are required including the Order Total (PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT).

The API is returning the following (JSON):

```
{"TIMESTAMP":"2017-06-03T15:13:26Z","CORRELATIONID":"ID","ACK":"Failure","VERSION":"2.700000","BUILD":"34310309","L_ERRORCODE0":"10400","L_SHORTMESSAGE0":"Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.","L_LONGMESSAGE0":"Order total is missing.","L_SEVERITYCODE0":"Error"}
```

I appreciate any kind of help with the above.

Thank you!

Comment: I know nothing of PayPal but, do you have a `?` for your first url parameter? (Ex `http://example.com/?apple=orange&value=fruit`)

Comment: @Terminus Thank you for your reply, I am using an ? for the URL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using a global variable for $version which was being overwritten. The API's error was due to the VERSION parameter passed. Correct version param was 98.